# Input widget(s) for recording the attributes of >=0 complex objects

Tags: r, forms, shiny

I would like to understand if there is some combination of widgets and panels that might enable the following use case:

I want users to be able to record the attributes of a complex object (here I'm using 'complex' loosely -- just a thing consisting of fields with values, some optional and not)

For instance, in the context of recording one's vehicles, we might want the application to do the following:

- Ask the user if they have any vehicles.
- If yes, surface a collection of fields for recording some set of attributes about their first vehicle

  - make
  - model
  - year
  - color
- After entering the first vehicle, ask if they have any remaining vehicles.

  - if yes, surface a form with the attributes above for vehicle #2
- then ask if they have any further vehicles

  - And then rinse and repeat.

I know how to do conditional panels and outputs based on input condition but I think I'm getting tripped up on how to populate objects in a collection of said objects of arbitrary length. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Some code would be helpful to understand your problem more precisely. Why can't you just store the answers in a dataframe and reset the inputs?